# How to keep the stream of ImageOutputStream in memory?

Tags: tiff, javax.imageio, twelvemonkeys

The following code uses twelvemonkeys to create a tiff file. The created file gets flushed to disk automatically. But I would like the file to be created in memory only. How to achive this with the ImageOutputStream?

```
try {
  // Create output stream
  ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(targetFile);

  try {
    writer.setOutput(output);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    TIFFImageWriteParam tiffWriteParam = (TIFFImageWriteParam) param;
    tiffWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);     

    TIFFImageMetadata metadata = (TIFFImageMetadata) createMetadata(sourceFile);     

    // Set dpi
    String nativeFormat = TIFFMedataFormat.SUN_NATIVE_IMAGE_METADATA_FORMAT_NAME;
    // Node nativeTree = metadata.getAsTree(nativeFormat);
    IIOMetadataNode newTree =
        new IIOMetadataNode("com_sun_media_imageio_plugins_tiff_image_1.0");
    IIOMetadataNode ifdNode = new IIOMetadataNode("TIFFIFD");
    newTree.appendChild(ifdNode);
    createTIFFFieldNode(ifdNode, TIFF.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT, TIFF.TYPE_SHORT, 2);
    createTIFFFieldNode(ifdNode, TIFF.TAG_X_RESOLUTION, TIFF.TYPE_RATIONAL, new Rational(300));
    createTIFFFieldNode(ifdNode, TIFF.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION, TIFF.TYPE_RATIONAL, new Rational(300));
    metadata.mergeTree(nativeFormat, newTree);

    IIOImage iioimage = new IIOImage(image, null, metadata);
    writer.write(metadata, iioimage, tiffWriteParam);
  } finally {      
    output.close();
  }
} finally {  
  writer.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent `ImageIO` from creating a disk cached `ImageOutputStream`, you may invoke the static `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`. The catch here, is that it will disable disk caching for `ImageIO` **globally**, which may not be desirable. In addition, you need to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or other in-memory structure, to actually store the TIFF image data.

For example:

```
ImageIO.setUseCache(false);  // Typically in a static initializer somewhere

...

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bytes)) {
    ... // Write image & meta data
}
```

Another option which does not affect `ImageIO` globally, is to replace the `ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(...)` call and just create a `new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(..)` wrapping a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to hold the result.

Example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (ImageOutputStream output = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(bytes)) {
    ... // Write image & meta data
}
```

A third option (which is likely to be slightly more efficient), is to subclass `ImageOutputStreamImpl` and implement yourself, using something more fancy, like in-memory `ByteChannel` or a `ByteBuffer` as backing. The cool thing about this, is obviously that you can use memory-mapped files or off-heap memory. But it will need some more effort to implement.

I'll probably go with the second option, unless profiling or otherwise tells you this doesn't perform well enough for you, then investigate option three.